# How to get all fields name via loop.

Tags: php, loops

I need help i want to get fields name via loop.

```
mysql_field_name($get,0)
```

I am using this function for get fields name but i don't find way to get all names via loop.

Comment: On the side: You should use mysqli or PDO : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Did you read the first comment from the manual page for that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql is deprecate and should not be used. Read the warning on top of http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php.

Anyways, try something like this:

```
$names = array();

$fieldsNumber = mysql_num_fields( $result );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fieldsNumber ; $i++ ) {

    $names[] = mysql_field_name( $result, $i );

}
```